# uint4 variable value printing in c

Tags: c++, c, printf

In my program I have `uint4 x` variable.
I have to print its value to stdout.

How can I implement it using `printf`?

Thank you in advance

Note:`uint4 x` a structure of 4 unsigned integers

Comment: `uint4` is not a standard type. What is its definition?

Comment: what is an unit4 x here?can you explain it clearly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`uint4` is  no standard type and there's no common definition. I know of projects where `uint4` refers to any of these:

- a 32-bit unsigned integer type (1)
- a 4-bit unsigned integer type, realized as a bitfield (2)
- a structure of 4 unsigned integers (3)

You'd print them like this:

```
// case (1)
#include <inttypes.h>
typedef uint32_t uint4;
uint4 x = 42;
printf("x = %" PRIu32, x);

// case (2)
typedef struct { unsigned value : 4; } uint4;
uint4 x = { 7 };
printf("x = %u", x.value);

// case (3)
typedef struct { unsigned x, y, z, w; } uint4;
uint4 quad = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
printf("x = %u, y = %u, z = %u, w = %u", quad.x, quad.y, quad.z, quad.w);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the format specifier for hex numbers, with a width of `1` (since a 4-bit number can have a maximum value of `0xf`):

```
printf("%1x", x);
```

Answer (score 2):

If this is the CUDA type `uint4` then you would do it like this in C:

```
uint4 v;

printf("v = { %u, %u, %u, %u }\n", v.x, v.y, v.z, v.w);
```

Comment: How is a `uint4` defined there? Are `x`, `y`, `z` and `w` bit-fields?

Comment: No, not bit-field. In CUDA it's a built-in vector type consisting of 4 x 32 bit unsigned ints which can be accessed as if it were a struct with elements x, y, z, and w

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't `printf("x=%d\n", x);` work?

What's a uint4?

Comment: It won't if `uint4` is of different size than `sizeof(int)`. If you did a cast `(int)x`, it would work if it is not a structure.

Answer (score 0):

Use int instead of uint4, I've never heard of uint4 before.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    printf("Value of x: %i", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively you can use `unsigned int` if you only want to store positive values.